# Lexical or preprocessor issue in Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I'am using react native: 0.41.2, react: 15.4.2 and cocoapods for firebase(https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm).
I have an issue while building the code. **'React/RCTEventEmitter.h', 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h', 'React/RCTViewManager.h', 'React/RCTDefines.h'** these files are not found error is throwing while running the project.

But these files are already in my project by clicking ctrl with that file name. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcnGm.png)

podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'Inspector' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Inspector
  react_native_path = "../node_modules/react-native"
  pod "React", :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  target 'Inspector-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'InspectorTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who facing this issue, it is due to header import issues with react native 0.41.2 along with cocoapods
To resolve these errors follow these steps

1`npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade`

2 go to your project root folder and do

```
react-native-git-upgrade
```

3 Solve conflicts if any occur while upgrading RN

4 Now remove React dependencies from pod file else you will have two React in schemes(One RN and One Pod) and it will cause `no input error` while building. Your pod file should look like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'Inspector' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Inspector   // Pods for your app, in this case firebase is used
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  target 'Inspector-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'InspectorTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

5 cd ios && pod install

6 Close Xcode and open .xcworkspace file

Comment: I have react native 0.50.3 and I'm having a similar issue. Do you think I can solve it with this as well ? @hariks